# setinterval and incremential value

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

I try to have a small slideshow with several Div name "nouvelleoffre_1 , nouvelleoffre_2, nouvelleoffre_3 ...

For that i Create 2 function defilementNouvellesOffres() and DefilementNouvellesOffresTimer

The first one is call at the event onload() of the html body. The second one is call with a set interval timer.

All works perfectly ... BUT the var **timer** is never inscrease. I think it's a basic scope problem. I try several things to solve it (a return, a timer++ in the Set interval.

Thanks for your help for solving it.

Here the code :

```
body.onload="defilementNouvellesOffres();"
function defilementNouvellesOffres(){
    div1 = "nouvelleoffre_";
    timer = 1;
    timerdefilement = setInterval(defilementNouvellesOffresTimer, 2000, div1, this.timer);
}

function defilementNouvellesOffresTimer(div1 , timer){
   //alert (timer);
   Effect.Fade(div1 + timer, { delay : 2 });
   timer++;
   //alert (timer);
   Effect.Appear(div1 + timer,  { queue: 'end' });  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what you want:

```
<body onload="">

<script type="text/javascript">
function defilementNouvellesOffres(){

    var SELF = {}
        SELF.div1 = "nouvelleoffre_";
        SELF.timer = 1;

    this.defilementNouvellesOffresTimer = function(){

        Effect.Fade( SELF.div1 + SELF.timer, { delay : 2 });
        SELF.timer++;
        Effect.Appear(SELF.div1 + SELF.timer, { queue: 'end' });
    }

    this.startInterval = function(){
        SELF.timerdefilement = setInterval("my_timer_function.defilementNouvellesOffresTimer();", 2000);
    }
    this.clearInterval = function(){
        clearInterval(SELF.timerdefilement);
    }
}
var my_timer_function = new defilementNouvellesOffres();
    my_timer_function.startInterval();
</script>
```

Comment: And it's possible to stop this Interval in another function ? I try to use  clearInterval(timerdefilement); in the other function. But it's don't work. Again a scope problem ?

Comment: I updated the answer. Use `my_timer_function.clearInterval();`

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables called `timer`.

One is global and implicitly declared when you `timer = 1`.

The other is local to the `defilementNouvellesOffresTimer` function and is declared in the arguments.

You copy the value of the global one into the local one, then you increment the value of the local one while leaving the global untouched.